# If $f(z)$ is analytic on the unit disk and $\left| f \right| \leq \frac{1}{1- \left| z\right|}$ then bound the derivative

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f(z)$ is analytic on $D = \{ z \in \mathbb{C}: \left| z\right| < 1\}$ and $\left| f \right| \leq \frac{1}{1- \left| z\right|}$ then show that $\left| f '(z) \right| \leq \frac{4}{(1 - \left|z\right|)^2}$.

---

I don't know what to do here, we know that the function is bounded by the series $\sum_k \left|z\right|^k$ and that it looks like we are taking the derivative at both sides of the inequality (I know that this is not correct). I tried to use Cauchy's integral formula without success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cauchy works applying it for a point $|z|<1$ in a radius $r<1-|z|$ so getting:

$f'(z)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{|w-z|=r}\frac{f(w)dw}{(w-z)^2}$ and then estimating to ($|dw|=rdt$):

$|f'(z)| \le \frac{1}{(1-(|z|+r))r}$ since $|w-z| \le r$ means $|w| \le |z|+r$ so $|f(w)|\le \frac{1}{1-|w|} \le \frac{1}{1-(|z|+r)}$

But now choosing $2r=1-|z|$ (to maximimize the denominator under the condition $r+|z| <1$) one gets $1-(|z|+r)=\frac{1-|z|}{2}$ hence

$|f'(z)|  \le \frac{4}{(1-|z|)^2)}$ so we are done

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3332098/42969 :)

Comment: @martin I vaguely remembered doing this a while ago as an answer but I find it hard to do a search on my own answers as at least in complex analysis those are in the hundreds, so I thought it faster to write a succinct answer

Comment: I found this one with [SearchOnMath](https://www.searchonmath.com/result?query=%24%7B+%5Cleft%7C+f+%27%28z%29+%5Cright%7C+%5Cleq+%5Cfrac%7B4%7D%7B%281+-+%5Cleft%7Cz%5Cright%7C%29%5E2%7D+%7D%24&page=1&tm=0&domains=). Usually I try [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Cleft%7C%20f%20%27(z)%20%5Cright%7C%20%5Cleq%20%5Cfrac%7B4%7D%7B(1%20-%20%5Cleft%7Cz%5Cright%7C)%5E2%7D%24) first, but for some reason it did not find a relevant result.